# Java Editor not opening my java code

Tags: java, editor, open-with

When I double-click one of the .java files from the Project Explorer, it does not open in the `Java Editor`.  I even tried to open it with `Open With -> Java Editor` to no avail.  I even made sure in `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors` and made the extension .java default to the `Java Editor`.

I just got this app virtually finished and I feel like I didn't change anything and now I cannot get a .java file to open.  If you look at the screenshot, you can see at the red box that the files seem to be open and at a certain line number and such.  Any suggestions how to get these files open and viewable?

[image]

Comment: My mistake for the title.  I have updated it to make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse goto 
`Window->Open perspective->Jave`
`Window->Reset perspective`

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested above.  Now I see windows on the right and bottom such as ````Task List````, ````Outline```` and such.  I still cannot see my java code.  The line number and character number (i.e.  54:13) are still visible and if I press up, down, left and right then I can navigate through my code; even though it is not visible.

Comment: I think better reinstall a new eclipse

Comment: Oh man, I am scared to touch Eclipse.  I would hate to mess things up with my project.  I'll back up and try to re-install Eclipse.  Thanks Vishal.

Comment: I'm re-installing now.  I will report back with the result.

Comment: I just got done with my download and installation.  The same result is still happening.  I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Try to create new project and tell me the result

Comment: Same result with a new project.  All I did last time was install the new Eclipse without un-installing the original one so my project was still in there.  I guess I will try to remove Eclipse completely from my laptop and try again.

Comment: That's how you have to do. That's why mentioned there about taking backup of workspace

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, go to

> Settings -> File types -> Files opened in associated applications
>
> Settings -> File types -> Java source files

in any of them, if a exception is shown in the lower panel with the name of the file you can't open, just remove it and apply changes